# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Tags: php

I'm writing PHP code to send user input to the database. And http://fwtest.ga/register.php is my URL. every time I click the URL or check the JSON data in JSONLint website I get "mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): "Number of variables doesn't match a number of parameters in prepared statement" here is Mycode

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname");

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `user` (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES 
('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password')");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'ssss', $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Edit your question fast, you shared sensitive information, that could cause some harm to you,

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the params and you are preparing the query at the same time, use `?` to tell mysql where to place the data,remove the variables from the sql string

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `user` (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES 
(?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried with that and I was declaring 5 variables and using only four. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I declared the five variables after a $con, and use only four of them mysqli_prepare function. Now it's working.